# Getting error in IE11 for javascript array

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I get this error below only in IE edge. It works in all other browser apart from this one. I want to figure out what is causing this error:
[image]

---

Code rather than screenshot:

```
var ui_tabsets = new Array();
```

Causing error:

> Object doesn't support this action.

Comment: Can we see the JS code prior to that line?

Comment: It's just initializing other variables:
var guar = "GUARFINSTATSLIST";
var period = "FSPERIODENDDATE";
var guarantor = "USEDIRASGUARANTOR";
var guarList = "DIRGUARSLIST";

Comment: What's wrong with the literal declaration? `var ui_tabsets = [];`

Comment: Have you tried to initialize `ui_tabsets` like this: `var ui_tabsets = [];` ? In theory is a better practice to use the literal declaration instead of use `new Array();`

Comment: It might be that some other script or code before yours is overriding the Array-type...

Comment: Not sure what's going on but creating an array with the `new Array()` syntax works just fine in Edge for me. I would still show the code prior to that line, even if it's just initializing variables.

Comment: Do you have an `id` in your HTML called `ui_tabsets`?

Comment: "IE edge" is a conflation of two distinct browsers. Are you saying this repros in Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer, or both?

Comment: @Sampson Still waiting for OP's response, but I'm guessing he means IE11 since that's what the title is, IE11 uses Edge document mode, and the [tag:microsoft-edge] tag was added in by Hkachhia, not OP. Either way, not enough info to reproduce this.

Comment: On that note, @Hkachhia please be sure a question is actually related to the tag you're adding when editing tags!

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the Array constructor cannot be found.. This means something has gone wrong elsewhere. Perhaps you've closed an iframe this was running on or something that's lost you your HttpContext, more often this issue manifests with the error `Can't execute code from a freed script`. Webkit browsers will create you a new HttpContext if you try to call a function outside of a context and doesn't destroy contexts as eagerly as IE does so this issue probably won't occur in those browsers.

To find out where the problem is, create watches for `Array` in the debugger and step through the code leading up to this line, at some point you'll notice Array has gone. Work out how/why that line of code is releasing your context.